# FindResource returns NULL when trying to load a font from resources

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource

I am trying to load a font from my resources. This is the call I use, which currently returns NULL and therefore fails:

```
HRSRC rsrcData = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDF_ROBOTBLACK), L"FONT");
```

I added the font resource to my Resource.rc file, which now lists the following:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Font
//

IDF_ROBOTBLACK          FONT                    "Resources\\Fonts\\Roboto\\Roboto-Black.ttf"
```

Additionally, this is what my Resource.h looks like:

```
#define IDF_ROBOTBLACK                  108
```

As far as I can tell, this should be all there is to the whole process.

I already successfully managed to load another resource format, "PNG", which was added as a new, custom resource type as well, following the same procedure while only replacing "FONT" with "PNG" where it is due.

However, compared to my "PNG" loading approach, the "FONT" is never found. FindResource returns NULL, no matter what happens.

The error code returend by GetLastError() is 1813.

My concern is that .ttf is not really supported at all. I previously added all kinds of formats to my solutions resources, like .exe and .png, .jpg, but .ttf was not even suggested in the file picker when adding the resource.

Is it just not meant to be stored this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FONT` is a [standard resource type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908411.aspx), unlike `PNG`. Therefore you must use `RT_FONT` instead of `L"FONT"`.

The resource declaration can remain as:

```
IDF_ROBOTBLACK FONT "filename.ttf"
```

The resource must then be located as follows:

```
FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDF_ROBOTBLACK), RT_FONT);
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
IDF_ROBOTBLACK xfont "filename.ttf"
```

```
FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDF_ROBOTBLACK), L"xfont");
```

This would work because `xfont` is not a standard resource (same as `PNG`).

Or, you can always use `RCDATA` and `RT_RCDATA`.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you load your resource after the findResource?

```
        if (rsrcData)
        {
            HGLOBAL hGlob = NULL;
            if (HGLOBAL hGlob = LoadResource(inj_hModule, rsrcData))
            {
                DWORD dwResSize = SizeofResource(inj_hModule, rsrcData);
                std::cout << "Ressource Found size 0x" << std::hex << dwResSize << std::endl;
                LPVOID pRes = LockResource(hGlob);
                std::cout << "Ressource Found at 0x" << std::hex << pRes << std::endl; ...
```

This is a test to known where on memory and how mutch size you font cost.

1 . in this step : a little function running and tested.  Try with all your resources fonts added to your project, regards.

```
    static void GetFont(HMODULE module, LPCSTR resource, std::string name) {
    if (exists(path(name))) return;

    HGLOBAL     res_handle = NULL;
    HRSRC       res;
    char *      res_data;
    DWORD       res_size;

    // We miss error handling on most of them - be careful!
    res = FindResource(module, resource, RT_RCDATA);
    if (!res) return;
    res_handle = LoadResource(module, res);
    if (!res_handle) return;
    res_data = (char*)LockResource(res_handle);
    res_size = SizeofResource(module, res);

    std::ofstream stream;
    stream.open(name, std::ios::binary);
    stream.write(res_data, res_size);
    stream.close();

    AddFontResource(name.c_str());
}
```

2. Add them to the registry (you'll need to disable UAC or ask the user for permission)

You can just look at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts to see how to do it.

3. Once you are done loading all fonts you can broadcast the change

   ```
   SendMessage(hWnd, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
   ```
4. Call this function in ISurface

   ```
   virtual void ResetFontCaches() = 0;
   ```
5. Test and gl :)

   ```
   Interfaces::Surface()->SetFontGlyphSet(font, XorStr("Open Sans Bold"), 22, 300, 0, 0, FONT_CREATE_ANTIALIASED);
   ```

You are to adapt to your context rendering, regards.

Comment: I am doing it just the way you describe in your code snipped. However, it doesn't matter what happens afterwards, as LoadResource fails with rsrcData being NULL

Comment: @Sossenbinder I just adding a function that do the job, it run for me ;) gl for the next, regards.

Comment: You can also use `AddFontMemResourceEx`, as opposed to reading from resource and saving to disk.